# express-session Меняет сессию при закрытии браузера

Tags: node.js, сессия, express, express-sessions

есть сервер на express (4.16.3), вместе с ним работает модуль express-session(1.15.6).

Вот как это выглядит в коде:

```
// ...
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new MongoDBStore({
    uri: 'my-url',
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}))
// ...
```

Суть проблемы:
Открываю Яндекс браузер - присваивается сессия, потом закрываю его и когда открываю заново - НОВАЯ сессия.
Дело в том, что к сессиям привязана авторизация.

Проблема наблюдается в Яндекс браузере, microsoft EDGE и в мобильных браузерах, при этом в google chrome и opera работает правильно.

Помогите решить проблему или может быть чем-то можно заменить модуль express-sessions

Comment: Прочитать документацию по express-session. В частности про cookie

Comment: Для чего писать подобные ответы? Не знаете - не пишите. Если знаете в чём проблема, напишите как решить. Мне не нужно ограничивать время хранении сессии, мне нужно, чтобы она никуда не девалась в определённых браузерах. Я же написал, что в хроме, например, всё в порядке. Так как оно должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, нужно явно указывать, чтобы время сессии было не ограничено. Достаточно добавить cookie:{ maxAge: 60000}.

Но как сделать время не ограниченным? (maxAge: null не работает)

```
// ...
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000},
  store: new MongoDBStore({
    uri: 'my-url',
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}))
// ...
```

Comment: cookie: { maxAge: 9000000000000} или cookie: {expires: new Date(253402300000000)}. Спасибо @feiiiiii